# Redirection error in spring MVC (http status 404 the requested resource is not available jsp )

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I started learning Spring MVC and while developing project, I am facing some issues. My controller class is able to handle first request "/" and giving me the home page. From home page on clicking the href I want to redirect to another page i.e ContactForm. I am defining the same in controller class.

Below the controller class and JSP pages.

Home.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Contact Manager Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <h1>Contact List</h1>
            <h3><a href="/newContact">New Contact</a></h3>
            <table border="1">
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Action</th>                 
                <c:forEach var="contact" items="${listContact}" varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                    <td>${contact.name}</td>
                    <td>${contact.email}</td>
                    <td>${contact.address}</td>
                    <td>${contact.telephone}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/editContact?id=${contact.id}">Edit</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="/deleteContact?id=${contact.id}">Delete</a>
                    </td>                             
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>             
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ContactForm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>New/Edit Contact</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>New/Edit Contact</h1>
        <form:form action="saveContact" method="post" modelAttribute="contact">
        <table>
            <form:hidden path="id"/>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Telephone:</td>
                <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {   
    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;  
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{     
        List<Contact> listContact = contactDAO.list();
        model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
        model.setViewName("home");   
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        model.addObject("contact", newContact);
        model.setViewName("ContactForm");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
        contactDAO.saveOrUpdate(contact);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        contactDAO.delete(contactId);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Contact contact = contactDAO.get(contactId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
        model.addObject("contact", contact);     
        return model;
    }
```

Please provide your valuable suggestion.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check the answer I posted, accept if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a fundamental mistake. Say your project name is `neeraj-proj`, so the url to access is `localhost:8080/neeraj-proj`. When you hit link `<h3><a href="/newContact"></h3>`, you are actually hitting `localhost:8080/newContact` instead of `localhost:8080/neeraj-proj/newContact`

> The fix is to simply append a `.` to all of your `href links`. E.g.
> `<h3><a href="./newContact">New Contact</a></h3>`
>
> **Note:** Browser considers `localhost:8080` as the `base url` or the
> `host url`.

Similarly `<a href="./editContact?id=${contact.id}">Edit</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to "specify" the right url: Bikram Kundu has explained it his answer. But the solution is much more easier: use [`<c:url>`](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jstl-curl-core-tag/)*-tag (or [`<spring:url>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html)) and let it do the complicated stuff.

The key is that `<c:url>` (and `<spring:url>`) allow you to specify the url in an APPLICATION relative style!

For example `<c:url value="/newContact">` will become a domain relative url `/<YOUR_APP>/newContact`

** if someone knows the url for (official) `<c:url>` reference, please add it*

Comment: @Nerraj: the stackoverflow way to say thanks, is to vote up